# How can I specify/define a coder for a class that wraps TableRow

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have defined a class that wraps `com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow` class defining it as a internal member

```
public class TableRowWrapper implements Serializable {

    private TableRow tableRow;

    public TableRowWrapper() {
    } 
...
}
```

I have also some `DoFn` that processes input/output instances of that `TableRowWrapper` class resulting in a `PCollection<TableRowWrapper>`. I've tried annotating that class with `@DefaultCoder(SerializableCoder.class)` and `@DefaultCoder(ArvoCoder.class)` but it always fails to code because it can't find a coder for the member attribute instance of `TableRow`.
Here is an example when using `ArvoCoder`

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element 'com.test.bigquery.api.TableRowWrapper@5129e8a6' with coder 'AvroCoder'.
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.StandardCoder.getEncodedElementByteSize(StandardCoder.java:177)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.StandardCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(StandardCoder.java:191)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.WindowedValue$FullWindowedValueCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(WindowedValue.java:633)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.WindowedValue$FullWindowedValueCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(WindowedValue.java:542)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.MapTaskExecutorFactory$ElementByteSizeObservableCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(MapTaskExecutorFactory.java:429)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputObjectAndByteCounter.update(OutputObjectAndByteCounter.java:115)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowOutputCounter.update(DataflowOutputCounter.java:61)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:46)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:157)
    at      com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:329)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:483)
    at   com.test.cdf.wrapper.pipeline.DataflowPipeline$TableRowToWrapperDoFn.processElement(DataflowPipeline.java:203)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: in com.test.bigquery.api.TableRowWrapper in com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow in array null of array in field f of com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow in field tableRow of com.test.bigquery.api.TableRowWrapper
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:145)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:58)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder.encode(AvroCoder.java:227)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.StandardCoder.getEncodedElementByteSize(StandardCoder.java:174)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.StandardCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(StandardCoder.java:191)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.WindowedValue$FullWindowedValueCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(WindowedValue.java:633)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.WindowedValue$FullWindowedValueCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(WindowedValue.java:542)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.MapTaskExecutorFactory$ElementByteSizeObservableCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(MapTaskExecutorFactory.java:429)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputObjectAndByteCounter.update(OutputObjectAndByteCounter.java:115)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowOutputCounter.update(DataflowOutputCounter.java:61)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:46)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:157)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:329)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:483)
    at com.test.cdf.wrapper.pipeline.DataflowPipeline$TableRowToWrapperDoFn.processElement(DataflowPipeline.java:203)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(DoFnRunner.java:189)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.processElement(DoFnRunner.java:171)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase.processElement(ParDoFnBase.java:193)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:171)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:117)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:66)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:234)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:171)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:137)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:147)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:132)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.writeArray(ReflectDatumWriter.java:67)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:68)
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeField(GenericDatumWriter.java:114)
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.writeField(ReflectDatumWriter.java:175)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:104)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:66)
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeField(GenericDatumWriter.java:114)
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.writeField(ReflectDatumWriter.java:175)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:104)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:66)
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:143)
    ... 31 more
```

How can I define a coder for this class?

Comment: It appears either that AvroCoder is inappropriate for your custom type and you need to [define a custom Coder<T>](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/data-encoding), or you need to think more carefully about what the first cause of the exception was: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: in com.test.bigquery.api.TableRowWrapper in com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow in array null of array in field f of com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow in field tableRow of com.test.bigquery.api.TableRowWrapper`

Answer (score 4):

As you've noticed, since [`TableRow`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/TableRow.html) is not [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), you won't be able to use [`SerializableCoder`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/SerializableCoder).

In order to encode nullable values, Avro’s automatic schema generation requires either an [explicit union schema including null](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/spec.html#Unions) via [`@AvroSchema`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/api/java/org/apache/avro/reflect/AvroSchema.html) annotation or a [`@Nullable`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/avro/reflect/Nullable.html) annotation -- specifically [`org.apache.avro.reflect.Nullable`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/avro/reflect/Nullable.html) not `javax.annotation.Nullable`. These are not present in [`TableRow`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/TableRow.html), so [`AvroCoder`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/AvroCoder) is also inapplicable.

Perhaps the easiest way to provide a coder for your `TableRowWrapper` is to do so directly a via thin wrapper on [`TableRowJsonCoder`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/TableRowJsonCoder):

```
class TableRowWrapperCoder extends CustomCoder<TableRowWrapper> {

  private static final Coder<TableRow> tableRowCoder = TableRowJsonCoder.of();

  @Override
  public void encode(TableRowWrapper value, OutputStream outStream, Context context)
      throws IOException {
    tableRowCoder.encode(value.getRow(), outStream, context);
  }

  @Override
  public TableRowWrapper decode(InputStream inStream, Context context)
      throws IOException {
    return new TableRowWrapper(tableRowCoder.decode(inStream, context));
  }

  ...
}
```

You can register this coder for your entire pipeline via

```
pipeline.getCoderRegistry()
    .registerCoder(TableRowWrapper.class, new TableRowWrapperCoder());
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, with the additional pain of having additional members in my analogous `TableRowWrapper` class. Do you have any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: I would suggest opening a new question so the details of your case can be part of the record on StackOverflow.

Comment: You're right, but I already came up with a custom coder, which solved my needs. I'll write a blog post on this and post the link below. :)